# Unable to unmarshall XML using Jaxb and XMLPath

Tags: java, xpath, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I have an XML which needs to be mapped to a Java object i.e. a DTO. My XML has some wrapper elements which don't have any java objects in my DTO.. my XML looks something like this

```
<UseCaseView>
<FindCandidates>
    <CandidatesRequest>
        <APIRequest>
            <Code>Code</Code>
        </APIRequest>
    </CandidatesRequest>
</FindCandidates>   </UseCaseView>
```

The "FindCandidates" and "CandidatesRequest" are just wrapper elements and "APIRequest" is again a DTO..

I am using XMLPath like this in my DTO.. My Dto looks like this..

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "UseCaseView")
 public class FindRequestDTO implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5528726225975606325L;

private ApiRequestDTO apiRequest;


@XmlPath("FindCandidates/CandidatesRequest/APIRequest")
public ApiRequestDTO getAPIRequest() {
    return apiRequest;
    .........
```

This is not mapping the APIRequest element to my ApiRequestDTO, if I remove the two wrapper elements and 
map directly using XMLElement(name = "APIRequest") it works... But I need to ignore the two wrapper elements and construct my DTO.. 
I have added the Jaxb.properties file with

```
"javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory"
```

in my resources folder.

can someone help me to know whats going wrong here..

thanks,

Comment: When you create the `JAXBContext` what is the implementation class that is returned?  The following example may help:https://github.com/bdoughan/blog20110908.  If not I'll post an answer tomorrow.

Comment: @Blaise - thx for quick reply.. the implementation class returned is com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl

Comment: Do you have the eclipselink.jar on your classpath?  The example I linked to in my previous comment is all setup to compile and run using Maven.

Comment: Yeah.. my setup looks same.. I have the dependency added and have eclipselink.jar in my classpath... I am doing it in the same way as u did in your googledemo.. But in YahooDemo, you have some binding.xml.. I am not doing that way...

Comment: Do you have the jaxb.properties in the same package as your domain model?

Comment: appreciate your patience dude.. this is how I am creating the context JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(toClass);

Comment: what should be the implementation class that it should return?

Comment: You should get back org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.  Where you able to run the example I had on GitHub?

Comment: You could avoid the normal bootstrap process and use one of the org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, I got that thought but I was wondering what to pass in for properties, I just passed null and it worked out.. I really appreciate your help.. thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Below is a complete example that should help.

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to add a file called `jaxb.properties` with the following entry in the same package as your domain model.

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**FindRequestDTO**

```
package forum9881188;

import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "UseCaseView")
public class FindRequestDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5528726225975606325L;

    private ApiRequestDTO apiRequest;

    @XmlPath("FindCandidates/CandidatesRequest/APIRequest")
    public ApiRequestDTO getAPIRequest() {
        return apiRequest;
    }

    public void setAPIRequest(ApiRequestDTO apiRequest) {
        this.apiRequest = apiRequest;
    }

}
```

**ApiRequestDTO**

```
package forum9881188;

public class ApiRequestDTO {
}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum9881188;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(FindRequestDTO.class);

        FindRequestDTO fr = new FindRequestDTO();
        fr.setAPIRequest(new ApiRequestDTO());

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(fr, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UseCaseView>
   <FindCandidates>
      <CandidatesRequest>
         <APIRequest/>
      </CandidatesRequest>
   </FindCandidates>
</UseCaseView>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html
- https://github.com/bdoughan/blog20110908

---

**UPDATE**

If for some reason you can't get the MOXy implementation of `JAXBContext`, you can always use the native APIs to bootstrap.  When using the native APIs you do not need the `jaxb.properties` file:

```
package forum9881188;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(FindRequestDTO.class);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] {FindRequestDTO.class}, null);

        FindRequestDTO fr = new FindRequestDTO();
        fr.setAPIRequest(new ApiRequestDTO());

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(fr, System.out);
    }

}
```

Comment: When I try the update solution I got :Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext() is applicable for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.Object;, null) values: [[class CommonSvcRs], null]
Possible solutions: createContext([Ljava.lang.Class;, java.util.Map), createContext(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader), createContext([Ljava.lang.Class;, java.util.Map, java.lang.ClassLoader), createContext([Ljava.lang.reflect.Type;, java.util.Map, java.lang.ClassLoader), ...